# libjpeg PIL django image display

Tags: django, libjpeg

I installed PIL.
I can import PIL (with no error message)

Then I ran the code mentioned here:

[Python images display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166221/python-images-display)

And I get this error message:

IOError: decoder jpeg not available

I understand this is Library called libjpeg and (?) it should be installed already.
Or is it part of PIL?
Where is it installed if so?
And if not where can I download it?

What I would like to achieve (and seem to run in one problem after the other), would be simply explainable as a Webgallery which I than want to tweak. But first I need Django to get images from the MEDIA_ROOT and display them in the browser when somebody calls a URL. And then I need one button (Next).

And if Christmas and Easter will fall on the same day I want to get the timestamp of that button click.

I thought that would be a breeze. But now I am in a storm of libjpeg and PIL an Tkinter and Models and photologue and ImageField() and.

If anybody has done that (I guess any simple Image display on a Blog) I would be very very glad to hear this expierence.

I somehow cant understand the standard way to do this and every time I think I have the solution, there is some library missing or it is slightly not what I was looking for.

Thanks for the time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote an article on how to get libjpeg, PIL to work on Snow Leopard.

http://appelfreelance.com/2010/06/libjpeg-pil-snow-leopard-python2-6-_jpeg_resync_to_restart/

Hope you might find this handy

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://rodesia.org/2008/03/14/installing-pil-on-the-mac/