# Closing an image after opening it with webbrowser.open (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, image

So basically I am trying to open an image and then close it after few seconds with time.sleep.
First I tried using

```
import Image
import time
myImage = Image.open("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\image.jpg")
myImage.show()
time.sleep(5)
```

but this didn't work out well, since the image didn't even open because Windows Photo Viewer couldn't find the file. However when I use webbrowser.open like this

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\image.jpg')
webbrowser.close()
```

it successfully opens the file in Windows Photo Viewer, but closing doesn't seem to work. It gives me the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'close'
```

I've been searching for 2 days now with no working solution. The image is .jpg incase that matters. Also I don't want to change my default image viewer or modify things that other people who use this would have to modify as well. Using Python 2.7.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python images display](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166221/python-images-display)

Comment: I just found that question, I think that is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is my way to do it in windows_xp_sp3.**

```
import os, time
pic=["C:\\19.jpg","C:\\20.jpg","C:\\21.jpg","C:\\22.jpg"]
for p in pic:
    os.startfile(p)
    time.sleep(3)
os.system("taskkill /IM rundll32.exe")
```

Or, try this:

```
import subprocess, time
pic=["C:\\19.jpg","C:\\20.jpg","C:\\21.jpg","C:\\22.jpg","C:\\23.jpg","C:\\24.jpg","C:\\25.jpg","C:\\26.jpg","C:\\27.jpg"]
for p in pic:
    r=subprocess.Popen(p,shell=True)
    time.sleep(3)
#   r.kill() #It won't work, because "shell=True" is set.If you need to kill the "subprocess",just don't use it.
```

Like This:

```
import os,subprocess, time
pic=["C:\\19.jpg","C:\\20.jpg","C:\\21.jpg","C:\\22.jpg","C:\\23.jpg","C:\\24.jpg","C:\\25.jpg","C:\\26.jpg","C:\\27.jpg"]

for p in pic:
    r=subprocess.Popen(["rundll32.exe","shimgvw.dll,ImageView_Fullscreen",p])
    time.sleep(3)
    r.kill()
```

Comment: Ok, I changed the command to kill dllhost.exe instead of rundll32.exe, and it worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: Although it works fine when I run it on shell, when I run it in the console screen, terminating the process prints "SUCCESS: Sent termination signal to the process "dllhost.exe" with PID 7108." in the middle of the program. How could I hide this?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the wrong track here, to close it you would have to instruct the browser to close that tab, or window, or whatever.

The way to instruct a browser to do that, is not standardized, and the same holds for  something which is different for each browser, or indeed for each photo viewer.

If you want to control both opening and closing of a photo, you are better off doing that from within *your* Python program, instead of calling upon a different program such as a browser.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I understand what you mean, but as much as I am trying to figure it out, I still don't know what would I use to open+close the window from my python program. I am not familiar with the commands and the internet has not given me a working way to do it. Any way that would successfully open and close the photo would work for me.